# Assembling a Netty Message in the Handler

Tags: java, netty

I am in the process of prototyping Netty for my project. I am trying to implement a simple Text/String oriented protocol on top of Netty. In my pipeline I am using the following:

```
public class TextProtocolPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory
{
@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception 
{
    // Create a default pipeline implementation.
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();

    // Add the text line codec combination first,
    pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(2000000, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new TextProtocolHandler());

    return pipeline;
}
}
```

I have a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, a String Decoder, and a String Encoder in the pipeline.

As a result of this setup my incoming message is split into multiple Strings. This results in multiple invocations of the "messageReceived" method of my handler. This is fine. However , this requires me to accumulate these messages in memory and re-construct the message when the last string packet of the message is received.

My question is, what is the most memory efficient way to "accumulate the strings" and then "re-construct them into the final message". I have 3 options so far. They are:

- Use a StringBuilder to accumulate and toString to construct. (This gives the worst memory performance. In fact for large payloads with lots of concurrent users this gives non-acceptable performance)
- Accumulate into a ByteArray via a ByteArrayOutputStream and then construct using the byte-array (this gives a much better performance than option 1, but it still hogs quite a bit of memory)
- Accumulate into a Dymamic Channel Buffer and use toString(charset) to construct. I have not profiled this setup yet but I am curious how this compares to the above two options. Has anyone solved this issue using the Dynamic Channel Buffer?

I am new to Netty and its possible I may be doing something wrong architecturally. Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Sohil

**Adding my implementation of a custom FrameDecoder for Norman to review**

```
public final class TextProtocolFrameDecoder extends FrameDecoder 
{
public static ChannelBuffer messageDelimiter() 
{
      return ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] {'E','O','F'});
    }

@Override
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel,ChannelBuffer buffer) 
throws Exception 
{
    int eofIndex = find(buffer, messageDelimiter());

    if(eofIndex != -1)
    {
        ChannelBuffer frame = buffer.readBytes(buffer.readableBytes());
        return frame;
    }

    return null;
}

private static int find(ChannelBuffer haystack, ChannelBuffer needle) {
    for (int i = haystack.readerIndex(); i < haystack.writerIndex(); i ++) {
        int haystackIndex = i;
        int needleIndex;
        for (needleIndex = 0; needleIndex < needle.capacity(); needleIndex ++) {
            if (haystack.getByte(haystackIndex) != needle.getByte(needleIndex)) {
                break;
            } else {
                haystackIndex ++;
                if (haystackIndex == haystack.writerIndex() &&
                    needleIndex != needle.capacity() - 1) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (needleIndex == needle.capacity()) {
            // Found the needle from the haystack!
            return i - haystack.readerIndex();
        }
    }
    return -1;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you would get the best performance if you would implement your own FrameDecoder. This would allow you to buffer all the data till you really need to dispatch it to the next Handler in the chain. Please refer to the [FrameDecoder](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html) apidocs.

If you don't want to handle the detect of CRLF by yourself it would also be possible to keep the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder and just add a custom FrameDecoder behind it to assemble the ChannelBuffers that represent a line of text.

In both cases FrameDecoder will take care to minimize memory copies as much as possible by try to just "wrap" buffers and not copy them each time.

That said if you want to have the best performance go with the first approach, if you want it easy go with the second ;)

Comment: Thanks Norman for the pointer. Let me try to implement your suggestion and profile the app to see if this approach in fact works

Comment: Norman, I have implemented the second approach that you mentioned. Things work fine from a functionality standpoint. However, things don't look good from a scalability standpoint. I am profiling the system using 1000 concurrent users with each user submitting a 2MB size payload. I see that the CPU maxes out and the system comes to a crawl. When I revert to the original approach with the Message constructed in memory in the Handler, the scalability issue goes away except for the memory usage problem which is a bit high. I have a 2GB heap and it consumes 1.2GB during a profiling session.

Comment: With the custom FrameDecoder approach, do you think I may have left out some knob that needs to be tweaked to improve the scalability? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Could you share your implementation so I can review ?

Comment: Hi Norman, I have added the code for my implementation at the end of my question. Thanks

Comment: Seen your impl why not just use: 

new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192), ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] {'E','O','F'})); ?

Comment: The 8192 may need to get adjusted based on your needs

Comment: I made the above change and here is what I found. The decoding is accurate. On Scalability, the memory utilization is good. It only uses between 300-600MB during the session instead of the 1.2GB earlier. The only problem is the CPU utilization. Even though the system does not hang anymore the CPU stays at 90%. Btw I switched back to the default line delimiter and the CPU utilization came down  to 20% which is acceptable. Could there be a performance bug in the decoding process? Thanks