# Running Apache MINA and Netty within the same JVM

Tags: java, netty, mina

I need to run two services within my application. One is a text protocol based socket server and other is a http protocol based server. For the socket server I am using Apache MINA as the NIO Framework while for the http protocol I want to use the Netty HTTP implementation.

I considered consolidating into just one framework (Netty), but I am getting some performance problems with Netty when it comes down to processing large payloads. MINA (2.0.7) does a great job of handling such load on the socket server. I also looked at MINA AsyncWeb for the HTTP server but this project seems to be dead.

My question is, has anyone run into this architectural dilemma. Would it be ok to run both the frameworks within the same JVM on different sockets or is there some stepping on the toes that I am not aware of.

btw: I have run both frameworks as socket servers within the same JVM and successfully load tested them. All I need to do is convert the Netty socket server into a HTTP server.

Thanks
Sohil

Comment: Can you share in which problems you ran with Netty so we can fix it ?

Comment: Hi Norman, please see this thread (the comments) for details.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422043/assembling-a-netty-message-in-the-handler. Basically, with a large payload the memory utilization is fine but CPU usage is too high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not problem running both of them in the same JVM. It will just work, no need to worry